# How to plot a 3D surface with a simple black and white style?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

*Mathematica* has great plotting capabilities. However, sometimes what is needed is a very basic black and white plot without textures, lighting, glow and other complex features. So, here is my question: what kind of `Plot3D` options will allow me to get something similar to

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would say you go for the `Lighting` option:

```
Plot3D[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> {20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: In fact, `Lighting -> {White}` is enough.

Comment: yes, but I wanted to mention explicitly that it's the ambient light which prevents shading.

Comment: In V10 `PlotStyle->White` is necessary to deal with an orange plot. One can also add `PlotPoints->22, MaxRecursion->0` to obtain really old-school plot :)

Answer (score 20):

Just a few alternatives. (from @Mr.Wizard) If one prefers to have it simple but to keep shading, then

```
Plot3D[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> {20}]
```

[image]

Some may want to have transparent mesh

```
Plot3D[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Mesh -> {20}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0], MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5]]
```

or from @J.M.

```
Plot3D[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> FaceForm[None], PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> {20}]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have any thoughts about `ColorFunction -> (White &)` versus `Lighting -> "Neutral"`?  I typically use the latter.

Comment: For the second: `PlotStyle -> FaceForm[None]` works nicely, too.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `Lighting -> "Neutral"` is more efficient I think - I edited it into my code. Thx ;)

Comment: @J.M. Yes, nice observation ;)

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, through close reading of the docs for `Plot3D[]`, it would seem that `ColorFunction -> (White &)` is entirely equivalent to the default `ColorFunction -> Automatic`, so one does not really need to tweak `ColorFunction` for a plain Jane plot...

Answer (score 17):

If one wants a simple wireframe mesh, as in Vitaliy's answer, here's yet another method:

```
DeleteCases[Plot3D[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> {20}], _Polygon, ∞]
```

[image: wireframe plot]

---

As it turns out, however, there is an even simpler way to generate a nice wiremesh:

```
Plot3D[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> {20}, PlotStyle -> None]
```

Comment: There's a certain beauty to this approach.  "Polygons, begone!" :-)

Comment: That's more or less how I read the code, too. :)

Answer (score 7):

Just to mention, for me the [accepted answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22563/13757) does not bring the desired result with Mathematica 10. Instead, what I get when running

```
Plot3D[
  Cos[2 Norm[{x, y}]], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10},  
  Lighting -> {"Ambient", White},  
  PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> {20}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.1},  
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

is this:

[image: Orange looking 3d plot]

However, a color function did the difference for me:

```
Plot3D[
  Cos[2 Norm[{x, y}]], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10},  
  Lighting -> {"Ambient", White}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, White],  
  PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> {20}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.1}, 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: `ColorFunction -> (White &)` also works.

Comment: "Just to mention, for me the accepted answer does not bring the desired result with *Mathematica* 10. " - The default light sources changed in version 10(?), while the answers that came before you were done in version 8.

Comment: You should be able to get this with `PlotStyle->White` too. Might even be faster.