# Plot3D without Shading, how to suppress it?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I want to plot a surface `z=f[x,y]` with `Plot3D`. This time I want to suppress the shading. I just want the mesh on the surface.

Setting `ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, White]` there is still some gray in this plot.

**How can I suppress the shading altogether?**

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22562/how-to-plot-a-3d-surface-with-a-simple-black-and-white-style

Comment: I think you should at least rephrase your question. As we already know you meant something different than people understood. Additionally your accepted answer not only has not shading, it is only a mesh... Which is something different then shade less white surface.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In:

```
shading = Array[None &, {2, 2}]; (*{{None, None}, {None, None}}*)
Plot3D[Sin[x + y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, MeshShading -> shading]
```

Out:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was after.

Comment: @AdalbertHanßen since this is what you are after, isn't `PlotStyle -> None` enough?

Comment: @AdalbertHanßen Re Kuba's remark: On the face of it, the question is how to color the surface with no shading, not how to have no surface at al.  (An alternative way, but not as good as `PlotStyle -> None`, is `ColorFunction -> (Opacity[0] &)`, which is a way to adapt your original approach.)

Comment: @UnchartedWorks: Plot3D[Sin[x + y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
 MeshShading -> {{None, None}}] does the same.

Comment: @Kuba: Yes, Plot3D[Sin[x + y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle -> None] also has the same visual effect. This is the most obvious one and I have to ask myself, why I did not try this one before asking my question, especially since its description clearly points out what it does: "PlotStyle->None specifies that the main objects in a plot should not be drawn explicitly, though mesh and filling are not affected."

Answer (score 9):

You need to:

- Set [`Glow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Glow.html) on the surface.  This adds a solid colour component to the shading.
- Set the other components to `Black`, to avoid reflecting any light.

This method does not require changing the global lighting, so it will not affect other objects in the scene.

```
Plot3D[
 Sin[x] Sin[y],
 {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Glow[Pink]]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Glow[White]] would have been what I was after. How did you get that answer? Glow2 is not described in the help of Plot3D, however it is in the help of PlotStyle.

Comment: @AdalbertHanßen How you can figure it out: in `PlotStyle` we can use *graphics directives*.  It is listed [on the ref page of graphics directives](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GraphicsDirectives.html).  (But I do not remember where I saw this for the first time. Probably not on that page. I remembered `Glow` because I needed the same thing in the past.)

Comment: I looked up for Shading, but I found "As of Version 6.0, Shading has been superseded by ColorFunction." However I should have searched under Plot3D for substrings containing "Shading" to find a reference to MeshShading which is part of UnchartedWorks' solution. - Would it not be nice to have a function which asks for a search pattern (of the current help item) and then scans through all the descriptions of all Options directly or indirectly acessible from the current symbol (in my case: Plot3D) and which returns hyperlinks to all hits of the search pattern - ordered by option or sub-Option?

Comment: @AdalbertHanßen Did you want only a wireframe (like UnchartedWorks' answer), or a solid surface without gradient shading (like my answer)?

Comment: yes, that's what I was after. Thank you all.

Answer (score 8):

Another way is to set `Ambient` lighting on a white surface:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> White, 
 Lighting -> {"Ambient", Pink}]
```

[image]

Or plot `Pink` and `White` light.

Comment: Plot3D[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> White, 
 Lighting -> {"Ambient", White}] would have been what I was after. I had tried it with PlotStyle->White before, but there remained shadows which were wiped out by your lighting conbditions. How did you get that answer? How would one have to improve the help function of Plot3D such that someone wanting such a skeleton plot arrives at an answer without checking this group?

Comment: @AdalbertHanßen don't know how to improve documentation but that can be found after scanning options available for Graphics3D and Plot3D. Not easy to find but possible.